# Is there a way to compress 20 - 40mb images when uploading to S3?

Tags: amazon-s3

I am looking to create a way where when I upload a file to S3, I would want an original copy and compressed copy that stores in different folders in the same bucket (different bucket works too). I tried to do that with the serverless app repository 'compress'. However, it does not compress images > 4MB

The structure I want to create is:

1. I upload the file to S3
2. The original file (with the 100% file size) goes into one folder
3. A compressed copy is created that goes into another folder in the same bucket

Is there a way to do figure this out? I'm new to AWS

Comment: Create a Lambda that compresses the file and link it to the S3 events corresponding to new objects being created on S3.  References: [1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html) [2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html).  Not familiar with the serverless app 'compress' - personally, I would roll my own, but maybe you can try and debug why the serverless app doesn't work for images > 4MB.

Comment: If the serverless app 'compress' works by a similar mechanism but fails for big messages - maybe you can look at the Lambda logs to see if it fails for a reason that might be easy to fix.  Maybe it just times out.  Lambdas have a configured timeout: "The amount of time that Lambda allows a function to run before stopping it. The default is three seconds. The maximum allowed value is 900 seconds."  Or maybe it just needs some other minor configuration change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this by doing the following.

Uploaded file to S3 triggers a bucket event notification with a destination of an AWS Lambda. The Lambda reads the file from S3, compresses the file, and then saves the file to another folder in the same bucket